# How to limit my outbound connection in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops-server

I want to limit my Azure VM outbound connection. Only allow connections to some limited domains and the rest of the connections should be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the outgoing part of the network security group which is attached to your VM network interface or virtual network. if you have a bigger environment you could look into azure firewall.